# Reference variable assignment in java

Tags: java, reference

```
String s;
Class Node;

for(int i=0; i< s.length();i++)
{

     node= s.charAt(i);
     node=   new Node();

}
```

I want to make a reference variable whose name is that of the character.

Comment: by doing as node s.charAt(i) = new Node(); it pops out error :-"The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable". how this is related ? for(int i=0; i< s.length();i++) { node= ""+s.charAt(i); node = new Node(); }this shows no error where node is reference variable of Object class, (I have changed class node to class object )

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be asking whether you can create variables dynamically, named with values from the characters of a string. Something like the following perhaps, where the aim is to end up with variables of type `Node` named `a`, `b`, and `c`?

```
String s = "abc";
class Node {};

for (int i=0; i<s.length(); i++)
{
    Node s.charAt(i) = new Node();  // this is an error, it can't be done!
}
```

This can not be done in Java because there is no support for dynamically named variables. You must declare variables upfront in your code.

What you should use is an array, List or a Map. A [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) is probably the closest to what you want:

```
class Node {};

String s = "abc";
Map<Character, Node> nodes = new HashMap<Character, Node>();

for (int i=0; i<s.length(); i++)
    nodes.put(s.charAt(i), new Node());

System.out.println(nodes.get('a'));
```

Comment: thanks , by doing as node s.charAt(i) = new Node(); it pops out error :-"The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable". how this is related ? for(int i=0; i< s.length();i++)
 {
  
   node= ""+s.charAt(i);
    node = new Node();
  
 }this shows no error where node is reference variable of Object class, (I have changed class node to class object ),

Comment: That code is to demonstrate what _can not_ be done. The point is that you can not do what you want, i,e. dynamically create variables. You can, however, add nodes to a Map, List or array - which is what the second block of code demonstrates.

Answer (score 0):

You pass the character as a parameter of `Node`. as per your example, `node` is initialized as a `Node` object rather than taking the value of `charAt`.

```
String s;

for(int i=0; i< s.length();i++) {
     node = new Node(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

intially `s` is null if it's a local variable.

therefore your code shouldn't compile because you are using the length of a null value. even if you initialize `s` with a value,  your code shouldn't compile because you are assigning a char value to a type of `Class`.

I suggest you to use a map, if you need to name variables (through keys) in runtime.